# What is the change in flux through a loop that has been rotated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

We have a number of field lines perpendicular to one loop of wire with an area $A = 10\textrm{ cm}^2$. The magnetic field is$B= 7.2\times10^{-5}\textrm{ T}$.

You turn the loop and the flux decreases with 30%. Calculate the angle at which the turn is turned.

My idea was:

$\sin( \alpha ) = \dfrac{B_n}{B}$. If I continue this way I get $\alpha = 44^\circ$

My book however goes with:

$B_n = B\cos \alpha$, $\cos \alpha = 0.7$. If you continue this way you get $ \alpha = 46^\circ$.

Why is the latter correct? I have no idea at all how this is done.

I will draw a picture to show my confusion:

[image]

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: What is the definition of flux?  What type of vector product is used?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer My textbook on describes it as 'a measure for the number of magnetic field lines through an area', and we haven't had anything about vector products as school as of yet.

Comment: In many cases in physics it's easy to tell that *either* a sine or a cosine is called for. To decide which, try a limiting case. If $\alpha = 0$ (you don't change anything), your formula predicts $B_n = 0$, while the book predicts $B_n = B$. Which makes more sense?

Comment: @ChrisWhite That can come in very handy, thank you! But I would like to know the trigonometric reason for this, which would help me a lot.

Comment: Another approach: what fraction of the lines pierce the loop if the loop is in the plane perpendicular to the field?  If it is in a plane parallel with the field?  That should be a hint as to what the relevant reference angle and trig function should be.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Why is my drawing wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: You're drawing isn't wrong. What you have found in the angle between the field lines and the plane once it has been moved. However, the angle which the plane is rotated is 90-44 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\cos \alpha$, if the angle through which the loop is turned  wrt to the initial plane of the loop is $\alpha$. So, if the angle between the final plane and initial plane of the loop is $\alpha$, so is the angle between the final normal and initial normal. The final flux is therefore initial flux X $\cos \alpha$, which you can tell in two ways:

1. The projected area of the loop perpendicular to the magnetic field is $A \cos{\alpha}$
2. The magnetic field along the direction of the normal in the final position is $B \cos{\alpha}$

Comment: Why the 0.7? What is the logic behind this? I'm guessing it has to do with the 30% decrease but I don't know why.

Comment: Also, could you tell me why my drawing is incorrect?

Comment: You said that the flux decreases by 30%, which means $(B-B_n)/B=30/100=0.3$. With $B_n=B\cos\alpha$, this would give $1-\cos\alpha=0.3$ and so $\cos\alpha=0.7$...would it not?

Comment: @VijayMurthy I'm sorry, that makes sense. I however still don't understand why my drawing is incorrect?

Comment: Isn't $\alpha$ the angle between $B$ and $B_n$? In you diagram, it is between $B$ and the other side of the triangle (which would correspond to $B_t$, the transverse component). With $\alpha$ as the top angle in the triangle, wont you get $B_n=B\cos\alpha$...?

Comment: @VijayMurthy I see, but isn't the angle at which the loop is turned same as the angle between $B$ and $B_t$? I understand your logic, but I don't really see how the angle between $B$ and $B_n$ is the angle at which the loop is turned

Comment: No, it is not and you can convince yourself of this if you just hold a sheet of paper, locate the normal, turn the sheet by an angle and find the normal again. This is a very easy geometry to visualize and you should get it.